# Which classes implement hashCode?

Tags: java, collections, hashcode

I was wondering which `collection` classes in java use the `hashcode` of an object?

Are these just `HashSet`, `HashMap`, `HashTable` or `LinkedHashMap` or there are more?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question ? It's quite unclear what you are asking

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code of the Java libraries?

Comment: Open the source in your IDE, select Object.hashCode() and perform "Find Usages"  This will show you all the code which uses it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe i understand what you mean, you are wondering how a collection class finds an element in a collection class?

It depends on the collection class some use equals and hashcode, others use both. The hashcode of an object is meant to be unique, almost like an id for an object. I do not believe java has documentation of which collection classes use hashcode or equals for a comparison but you can download the jdk sources and check yourself!

Comment: "The hashcode of an object is meant to be unique" is a pretty big overstatement. [The docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) explicitly say that it's not required to be unique, just that it will improve the performance of hash tables.

Answer (score 0):

Taken directly from the [hashCode method’s JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--).

> This method is supported ***for the benefit of hash tables*** such as those
>   provided by HashMap.

So yes, the method is used for storing objects into Map implementations.
Please also note this article: [The-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/). I always refer to it when I have doubts about my hashCode implemetation and use.

Comment: I think he already knows that.  He is asking >>which classes<< use `Object.hashCode()`.

Comment: Yes. Like its gets used HashSet, HashMap what all more are there ?